# Required Field Validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I tried this code for validating empty field,But it doesn't works properly when call `javascript` it does not focus on Textbox,and code will execute continues.

Html Code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtholdername" runat="server" Width="60%"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" runat="server" Width="60%"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnsave" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return validateRegistrationMaster();" ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" />
```

Script

```
function IsBlank(obj) {
    if (obj) {
        if (!String.prototype.trim) { String.prototype.trim = function () { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); }; }
        if ((obj.value.trim().length == 0) || (obj.value == null)) {
            obj.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
function validateRegistrationMaster() {

  var Holder_Name = document.getElementById('<%= txtholdername.ClientID %>');
 var username = document.getElementById('<%= txtusername.ClientID %>');
 if ((!IsBlank(Holder_Name))) {
        Holder_Name.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if ((!IsBlank(username))) {
        username.focus();
        return false;
    } return true;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle your above code,if you could

Comment: i'm try running your code , in chrome browser. it's can running right. do you have check another browser ?

Comment: @KingJk I'm also running on chrome

Comment: Create Holder_Name obj by static name ? Like document.getElementById('txtholdername'); If can execute right,maybe you need check control client_id is right

Answer (score 0):

Use Required Field Validator instead of custom Javascript, while using Asp.Net Controls.

Example : [Click Here W3 Schools Link](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_reqfieldvalidator)

Code:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtholdername" Text="The holder name field is required!"
runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtusername" Text="The user namefield is required!"
runat="server" />
```